# can row headers be specified for angular material tables?

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

I looked through https://material.angular.io/components/table and can see how to specify column headers, but I don't see a way to specify row headers.

From a pure html perspective, I want to end up with something like:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope='col'>name</th>
    <th scope='col'>age</th>
    <th scope='col'>favorite color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope='row'>fred</th>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope='row'>barney</th>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>brown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope='row'>wilma</th>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

where 'fred', 'barney', and 'wilma' are row headers.

I know angular material doesn't use native table tags, but rather custom tags and roles such as:

```html
<div role='grid'>
  <div role='row'>
    <div role='columnheader'>name</div>
    <div role='columnheader'>age</div>
    <div role='columnheader'>favorite color</div>
  </div>
  <div role='row'>
    <div role='rowheader'>fred</div>
    <div role='gridcell'>35</div>
    <div role='gridcell'>orange</div>
  </div>
  <div role='row'>
    <div role='rowheader'>barney</div>
    <div role='gridcell'>32</div>
    <div role='gridcell'>brown</div>
  </div>
  <div role='row'>
    <div role='rowheader'>wilma</div>
    <div role='gridcell'>33</div>
    <div role='gridcell'>white</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(The above is showing `<div>` elements instead of `<mat-table>`, `<mat-header>`, etc because I wanted the `role=` to stand out)

Is there a way to get row headers?  If I bring up the code inspector for the first table in https://material.angular.io/components/table,

[image: table snippet]

the 'Hydrogen' cell is defined as:

```html
<mat-cell _ngcontent-c20="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell">Hydrogen</mat-cell>
```

If I look at the column header, 'Name', it's defined as:

```html
<mat-header-cell _ngcontent-c20="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name ng-star-inserted" role="columnheader">Name</mat-header-cell>
```

If I merge the two and use the `<mat-header-cell>` tag from the column header and the `class` definition from `<mat-cell>` (for styling purposes), and also change the `role` from `columnheader` to `rowheader`, I get a valid row header.

```html
<mat-header-cell _ngcontent-c20="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name ng-star-inserted" role="rowheader">Hydrogen</mat-header-cell>
```

When I use a screen reader and I navigate vertically through a column, the row header is properly read before the table cell is read.  It works great.  I just need a way to specify a row header in angular material.

Comment: What do you mean by "row header"? Do you want to have a header shown for each row rather than the static table level header?

Comment: you can write a custom directive, which takes view-container-ref.. and then manipulate the dom to replace the attribute value

Answer (score 4):

Since it's now possible to create Angular table with table tags you can simply specify scope attribute on specific cell. Also, if you want to remove all default `role` attributes then you can use attribute binding with `null` value `[attr.role]="null"`:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef scope="col" [attr.role]="null"> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" scope="row" [attr.role]="null"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef scope="col" [attr.role]="null"> Age </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.role]="null"> {{element.age}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="favorite color">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef scope="col" [attr.role]="null"> Favorite Color </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.role]="null"> {{element['favorite color']}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" [attr.role]="null"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [attr.role]="null"></tr>
</table>
```

This should lead you to the same result as you required from a pure html perspective(https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/two-headers/)

The only one part that you can't override declaratively is any table section(`thead role="rowgroup"`, `tbody role="rowgroup"`, `tfoot role="rowgroup"`) but anyway if it's required to remove(or change) those `role` attributes you can do it inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook of your host component or dedicated directive:

```
@ViewChild('tableRef', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) tableRef: ElementRef<HTMLTableElement>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const table = this.tableRef.nativeElement;
  Array.from(table.children).forEach(section => {
    section.removeAttribute('role');
  })
}
```

don't forget to assign template reference variable `<table #tableRef` to your table

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdwsfx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**